# minikube 0.30.0 DNS not working on CentOS 7 with Docker 18.06.1-ce and vm-driver=none

Tags: docker, dns, kubernetes, minikube

I am experimenting with minikube for learning purposes, on a CentOS 7 Linux machine with Docker 18.06.010ce installed

I installed minikube using

```
minikube start --vm-driver=none"
```

I deployed a few applications but only to discover they couldn't talk to each other using their hostnames.

I deleted minikube using

```
minikube delete
```

I re-installed minikube using

```
minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

I then followed the instructions under "Debugging DNS Resolution"
(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/)
but only to find out that the DNS system was not functional

More precisely, I run:

1.

```
kubectl create -f https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/busybox.yaml
```

2.

```
# kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
command terminated with exit code 1
```

3.

```
# kubectl exec busybox cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local contabo.host
options ndots:5
```

4.

```
# kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-c4cffd6dc-dqtbt     1/1     Running   1          4m
kube-dns-86f4d74b45-tr8vc   2/3     Running   5          4m
```

surprisingly both kube-dns and coredns are running
should this be a concern?

I have looked for a solution anywhere without success
step 2 always returns error

I simply cannot accept that something so simple has become such a huge trouble for me
Please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting /etc/kubernetes and /var/lib/kubelet and /var/lig/kubeadm.yaml and restarting minikube I can now successfully reproduce the DNS resolution debugging steps (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/)

I bet some stale settings had persisted among minikube start/top iterations leading to inconsistent configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is working with coredns enabled and kube-dns disabled.

```
C02W84XMHTD5:ucp iahmad$ minikube addons list
- addon-manager: enabled
- coredns: enabled
- dashboard: enabled
- default-storageclass: enabled
- efk: disabled
- freshpod: disabled
- heapster: disabled
- ingress: disabled
- kube-dns: disabled
- metrics-server: disabled
- nvidia-driver-installer: disabled
- nvidia-gpu-device-plugin: disabled
- registry: disabled
- registry-creds: disabled
- storage-provisioner: enabled
```

you may disable the kube-dns:

```
minikube addons disable kube-dns
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the output of `kube-dns` pod below, it has only 2 of 3 containers running.

`kube-dns-86f4d74b45-tr8vc   2/3     Running   5          4m`

The last time I encountered this was when Docker's default `FORWARD` policy was `DROP`. Changing it to `ACCEPT` using below fixed the problem for me.

`iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

It might be other things too, please check the pod logs.

Comment: # iptables --list
Chain KUBE-SERVICES (1 references)
target  prot opt source               destination
REJECT  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.96.0.10      /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns has no endpoints */ udp dpt:53 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.96.0.10      /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:53 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.98.123.7     /* kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard: has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:80 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Comment: even worse, this is not always happening
sometimes I only see
`Chain KUBE-SERVICES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.98.123.7          /* kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard: has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:80 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable`

Comment: `#  kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system pod/kube-dns-86f4d74b45-XXXXX -c kubedns
...
E1025 12:27:58.105775       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/dns/pkg/dns/dns.go:150: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
`

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth mentioning that DNS resolution was lost after restarting the iptables.

I suspect this is iptables rules related, some rule ie being put by minikube and as it gets lost as part of iptables restart the problem re-appears

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the problem by re-installing Minikube after deleting all state files under /etc and /var/lib, but forgot to update.

This can be now closed.